# How to modify div using ajax and js helper in cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cakephp

Hello i am trying to modify div content after redirecting to the page using js link in cakephp. I have a div id `#vi-content` in Links index view.

```
$this->Js->link($value['Link']['link_title'], array('controller'=>'Links', 'action'=>'index'), array('class'=>'link_video','id'=>$value['Link']['id']))
```

I want to call this ajax function using js helper

```
var u=baseUrl+'/Links/view_video/'+$(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    url:u,
    success:function(data){
            $("#vi-cont").html(data);
            alert(u);
    }
    error:function(e){
        alert("Sorry there was error :"+u);
    }
});
```

But i am not familiar with js Helper in cakephp. Thanks in advance.